# Как можно остановить объект, имеющий rigidbody, во время прыжка?

Tags: unity3d

Есть объект, имеющий rigidbody. При нажатии на клавишу "Space" происходит увеличение его ускорения (velocity), и затем её понижение.

Каким образом можно вставить в момент наивысшей точки задержку? Так, чтобы объект вёл себя как на земле в течение пары секунд. Мог пройти пару шагов, сделать какое-то действие, и затем упасть.

```
[Header("Keyboard Input Settings")]
public KeyCode JumpButton = KeyCode.Space;
public KeyCode AttackButton = KeyCode.E;
private bool wasDelayedOnce = false;
private PlayerBehaviour _player;

public AnimationCurve JumpCurve;
public float JumpTime;

void Start()
{
    _player = GetComponent<PlayerBehaviour>(); 
}

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
        _player.runDir = _player.MInput;

    if (_player.Acc)
    {
        _player.Speed = Mathf.Lerp(_player.Speed, _player.AccelerationPower, _player.AccelerationTime * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    else
    {
        _player.Speed = Mathf.Lerp(_player.Speed, 0f, _player.DecelerationTime * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

public void KeyboardWalkAndAttack()
{
    _player.MInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(AttackButton))      // атаковать enemy
    {
        if (_player.Anim.GetBool("Attack") == false)
        {
            Debug.Log("Pressing E");
            _player.DetectEnemy();
        }
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)|| Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        _player.Acc = true;
    }
    else
    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.D))
    {
        _player.Acc = false;
        //_player.Speed = 0f;
    }
    if (_player.Acc)
    {
        _player.rb.velocity = new Vector2(_player.MInput * _player.Speed, _player.rb.velocity.y);
    }
    else
    {
        _player.rb.velocity = new Vector2(_player.runDir * _player.Speed, _player.rb.velocity.y);
    }
    _player.isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(_player.Feet.position, _player.feetRadius, _player.Groundlayer);

    KeyboardJump();

}

public void KeyboardJump()
{
    if (!_player.DoubleJump)
    {


        if (Input.GetKeyDown(JumpButton) && _player.isGrounded)
        {
            _player.JumpingVelocity = JumpCurve.Evaluate(JumpTime);
            _player.rb.velocity = Vector2.up * _player.JumpingVelocity;
        }
        if (_player.rb.velocity.y < 0)            //Ускорение падения
        {

            _player.rb.velocity = new Vector2(_player.rb.velocity.x, _player.rb.velocity.y * _player.FallAccelerationValue); 
        }

    }
    else
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(JumpButton) && _player.JumpsNum < 1)
        {
            ++_player.JumpsNum;
            _player.rb.velocity = (Vector2.up * _player.JumpingVelocity) + new Vector2(_player.rb.velocity.x, 0);
        }
        else if (_player.isGrounded && _player.JumpsNum > 0)
        {
            _player.JumpsNum = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Функция `KeyboardWalkAndAttack` вызывается раз в `Update` из функции `PlayerBehaviour`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, направление движения.

Answer (score 0):

Вам придётся после прыжка отслеживать `_player.rb.velocity.y` и как только станет отрицательным насильно обнулять `y` некий период времени который вам требуется.

```
enum kJumpStage { None, Track, Levitate }
kJumpStage JumpStage;
float LevitateTimer;
float LevitateTime = 3f;

void Update () {
    ...
    switch (JumpStage) {
        case kJumpStage.Track: {
            if (_player.rb.velocity.y < 0) JumpStage = kJumpStage.Levitate;
        } break;
        case kJumpStage.Levitate: {
            LevitateTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (LevitateTimer > LevitateTime) JumpStage = kJumpStage.None;
            _player.rb.velocity = new Vector3(_player.rb.velocity.x, 0, _player.rb.velocity.z);
        } break;
    }
}

public void KeyboardJump () {
    if (!_player.DoubleJump) {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(JumpButton) && _player.isGrounded) {
            ...
            JumpStage = kJumpStage.Track;
            LevitateTimer = 0;
        }
        ...
    } else {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(JumpButton) && _player.JumpsNum < 1) {
            ...
        } else if (_player.isGrounded && _player.JumpsNum > 0) {
            ...
            JumpStage = kJumpStage.None;
        }
    }
}
```